# passing a variable from a jframe to another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am attempting to read a name from a text field and then passing it to class that will file it into an array. The class I am trying to pass to functions as a phone book but I am trying to add a GUI. However, when i try to pass the variable from the jframe to the original class the program crashes. Here are the relevant parts of the original and the frame i am trying to passfrom
**MainPhonebook**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Phonebook {
    public static Entry[] contactList;
    public static int num_entries;
    public static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int i;
        char C;
        String code, Command;
        contactList = new Entry[200];
        num_entries = 0;
        readPhoneBook("PhoneBook1.txt");
        System.out.println("Codes are entered as 1 to 8 characters.\nUse"
                + " \"e\" for enter," + " \"f\" for find,"
                + " \"l\" for listing all the entries," + " \"q\" to quit.");
        Command = null;
        C = ' ';
        while (C != 'q') {
            System.out.print("Command: ");
            Command = stdin.next();
            C = Command.charAt(0);
            switch (C) {
            case 'e':
                addContact();
                break;
            case 'f':
                code = stdin.next();
                stdin.nextLine();
                i = index(code);
                if (i >= 0)
                    displayContact(contactList[i]);
                else
                    System.out.println("**No entry with code " + code);
                break;
            case 'l':
                sortList();
                listAllContacts();
                break;
            case 's':
                sortList();
                break;
            case 'q':
                CopyPhoneBookToFile("PhoneBook1.txt");
                System.out
                        .println("Quitting the application. All the entries are "
                                + "stored in the file PhoneBook1.txt");
                break;
            default:
                System.out
                        .println("Invalid command Please enter the command again!!!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addContact() {
        String name = stdin.next();
            String number;
            stdin.nextLine();
            contactList[num_entries] = new Entry();
            contactList[num_entries].name = name;
            System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
            number = stdin.nextLine();
            contactList[num_entries].number = number;
            System.out.print("Enter Notes: ");
            contactList[num_entries].note = stdin.nextLine();
            num_entries++;
        }
        public static void name(String name){
            contactList[num_entries] = new Entry();
            contactList[num_entries].name = name;   
        }
```

**Frame**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Name extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton Next;
    static TextField Name = new TextField(10);
    public Name()
    {
        super("Add New Contact");


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new JLabel("Add Contacts Name"));
        Next = new JButton("Next");
        add(Name);
        add(Next);
        Next.addActionListener(this);
        Next.setActionCommand("Open");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String name =Name.getText();
        Phonebook.name(name);
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if(cmd.equals("Open"))
        {
            dispose();
            new Number();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Name().setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This code mixes command-line style input with a GUI.  That is most likely the problem, since GUIs run on the EDT.

Comment: `contactList` is uninitialised and is therefore `null` when you try and call it.

Comment: Remove the `static` references in `PhoneBook`, replace the initialisation and loading of the data which currently in `PhoneBook.main` with a constructor.  Create a new instance of `PhoneBook` in your `Name` class and call it's instance methods as required.  Also, take a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  Rather then closing the current frame and opening a new one, simply change it's views or replace it's current content with new values